# How to get a certain path for saving and loading an mp3 (AIR for Android)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, filesystems

I'm using [shine mp3 encoder](https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy) for saving an *mp3* file. It has a `saveFile` method that can save an mp3 file. When that method runs (with only one argument name:String), it automatically triggers a pop up and asks the user where to save the mp3 file.

How can I prevent this pop up from AIR?

I need a path for saving that sound and I want to load and play that sound later.

Can someone help me find a way to prevent having to get the path from the user and instead use a fixed path that I can load back in later?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) and [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) classes in AIR - Which lets you save a file synchronously (or asynchronously) without user interaction.

Let's say your shine mp3 object is in a var called `myMp3`:

First, get a reference to your file (doesn't matter if it exists yet or not), use this same file for saving and loading:

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("MyMP3Name.mp3");
//applicationStorageDirectory is most appropriate place to save data for your app, and probably also the only place you'll have permission to do so
```

**To Save**

```
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
sream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeBytes(myMp3.mp3Data); //write the byte array to the file
stream.close();
```

**To Load**  (using the same File object from above)

```
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);

var sound:Sound = new Sound();
var mp3Bytes:ByteArray;
stream.readBytes(mp3Bytes); //read the bytearray in the file into the mp3Bytes var
stream.close();

sound.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray(mp3Bytes); //load that byte array into the sound object

sound.play();
```