# open xml, change XML data and Save it again using Action-script 3.0

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3, flash

This help is for a simple Air on Android app done using flash CC.
I am using a XML to store some settings data.
The first launch of the app will show a tutorial, once the user selects "Ok got it" Button, the data in the XML should be changed to false so that when it is launched again the tutorial wont play.

This is the **XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SETTINGS>
    <SET intro="true"></SET>
</SETTINGS>
```

This is the **AS3** to get data from the XML

```
var settingsXML: XML;
var settingsXMLLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
settingsXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("settings.xml"));
settingsXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e: Event): void {
    settingsXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    if (settingsXML.SET[0].@intro == true) {
        gotoAndStop("tutorial");
    } else {
        gotoAndStop("homepage");
    }
}
```

Now in another frame i need to change the xml "intro" to "false" and save it at the same location. Please help. how to do it?

And How to make

```
settingsXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("settings.xml"));
```

load xml from documentsDirectory, i mean this path

```
File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('App Name/data/settings.xml');
```

Comment: use the File and FIleStream classes, forget URLLoader.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515733/how-to-get-a-certain-path-for-saving-and-loading-an-mp3-air-for-android/30518230#30518230.  Instead of writeBytes,  you can just write the it like this:  `stream.writeUTF(settingsXML.toXMLString())`

Comment: For changing XML attribute, take a look on [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33542396/2256820), and to save it as a file again, from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31057995/2256820) ...